# What's the ritual of performing morning pooja at home

Tags: puja

I'm trying to get into the habit of doing pooja at home. Can someone give me the essential things that need to be done?

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure you will agree that taking a bath is essential in the morning after waking up. Especially so if you are about to do puja.

So, what exactly is bathing ? Seems simple enough, but when Yudhishtira was asked this question in Mahabharata, he answers weirdly :

> Snanam Mano Mala Tyagah
>
> Bathing is Mind Dirt Sacrifice

There are 6 types of dirt in the mind - Kama, Krodha, Moha, Lobha, Madha, Matsarya.

Everyday, these dirts accumulate in our thoughts, words and actions - Just as urine and stool accumulate in our bowels. And just as the latter need to be expelled from the body, the former should be from the mind.

How to do that ? Simple - Avoid acting on those impulses.

You feel the 'Kama' to drink coffee before bathing ? Avoid acting on that desire. Or resolve not to do so in future.

You feel the 'Krodha' to shout at your wife if she doesn't bring you coffee ? Avoid acting on that anger. Or resolve not to do so in future.

So on for each of the other 4 dirts. Once this type of 'bathing' is done, you are ready for puja :)

Comment: i beileve you are older generation where wife brings cofee to you? you are gifted now nobody brigns only thing some get is scolding and also now every one calls husband by name.. if in anger scolded as kid..(tough not mine)

Comment: @PrasannaR *"now every one calls husband by name"* - well, do the husbands respect their elderly parents, do daily rituals like sandhya-vandana (or puja for other varnas), avoid alcohol,porn,gambling etc.? one cannot expect rights without performing duties. if guys don't wear tilak, why should girls wear bindi ? if husbands don't respect yagnopaveeta (sacred-thread), why should wives respect their sacred thread (mangal sutra). There is no free lunch in the world ever.

Comment: 6 dirts like Kama, .. to matsarya i agree that should be removed but its not like what you described Kama is lustful toughts when someone closes eyes there mind uncontrolleable goes to lust.. that is Kama. (its not desire to drik cofee) similarly Krodha.. (vegence.. its not anger of not bring coffee) vegence on somebody like sikahandi, nauhusa.. so your analogy of 6 dirts is way off mark and trivial.. on lighter not note i didnt downvote your answer either this just for you to upgradde your answer as you might me knowingly already @ram

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm looking for more like what has to be done for puja rather than prerequisites

Comment: @PrasannaR, that's why i said 'coffee before bathing' - as in desires that are against shastra. nowadays almost nobody is going to do war based on vengeance. those kinds of krodha are for big warriors, whereas normal people have krodha at their own levels. everyone has krodha.